# Can't connect my producer / consumer pods to the Kafka pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am using simple YAML files, NO HELM.

FOR CONSUMER / PRODUCER / DB
I have created and uploaded the consumer, producer and postgis Docker Images and created the relevant kubernetes components (config maps, services and deployments).

FOR KAFKA
I have created the deployment and service yaml files.

This is the deployed service for the kafka server.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  namespace: default
  uid: 718544ff-850f-4f2e-9a95-66a1473ebd25
  resourceVersion: '161875'
  creationTimestamp: '2022-07-08T09:16:12Z'
  labels:
    name: kafka
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"name":"kafka"},"name":"kafka-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"kafka-port","port":9092,"protocol":"TCP"}],"selector":{"app":"kafka","id":"0"},"type":"ClusterIP"}}
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-07-08T09:16:12Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
        f:spec:
          f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
          f:ports:
            .: {}
            k:{"port":9092,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
          f:selector: {}
          f:sessionAffinity: {}
          f:type: {}
spec:
  ports:
    - name: kafka-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka
    id: '0'
  clusterIP: 10.111.155.87
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.111.155.87
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

This is the deployment for the kafka server

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker0
  namespace: default
  uid: 4a503b64-6055-4285-ab90-b18d290c1a31
  resourceVersion: '185462'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2022-07-08T09:16:05Z'
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '1'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"kafka-broker0","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"kafka","id":"0"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"kafka","id":"0"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT","value":"9092"},{"name":"KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME","value":"kafka-service"},{"name":"KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT","value":"zoo1:2181"},{"name":"KAFKA_BROKER_ID","value":"0"},{"name":"KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS","value":"power_plant_topic:1:1"}],"image":"wurstmeister/kafka","name":"kafka","ports":[{"containerPort":9092}]}]}}}}
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-07-08T09:16:05Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:spec:
          f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
          f:replicas: {}
          f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
          f:selector: {}
          f:strategy:
            f:rollingUpdate:
              .: {}
              f:maxSurge: {}
              f:maxUnavailable: {}
            f:type: {}
          f:template:
            f:metadata:
              f:labels:
                .: {}
                f:app: {}
                f:id: {}
            f:spec:
              f:containers:
                k:{"name":"kafka"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:env:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"name":"KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"KAFKA_BROKER_ID"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                  f:image: {}
                  f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                  f:name: {}
                  f:ports:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"containerPort":9092,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:containerPort: {}
                      f:protocol: {}
                  f:resources: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
              f:dnsPolicy: {}
              f:restartPolicy: {}
              f:schedulerName: {}
              f:securityContext: {}
              f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-07-11T07:56:27Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
        f:status:
          f:availableReplicas: {}
          f:conditions:
            .: {}
            k:{"type":"Available"}:
              .: {}
              f:lastTransitionTime: {}
              f:lastUpdateTime: {}
              f:message: {}
              f:reason: {}
              f:status: {}
              f:type: {}
            k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
              .: {}
              f:lastTransitionTime: {}
              f:lastUpdateTime: {}
              f:message: {}
              f:reason: {}
              f:status: {}
              f:type: {}
          f:observedGeneration: {}
          f:readyReplicas: {}
          f:replicas: {}
          f:updatedReplicas: {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
      id: '0'
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: kafka
        id: '0'
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: wurstmeister/kafka
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
              value: '9092'
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: kafka-service
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zoo1:2181
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: '0'
            - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
              value: power_plant_topic:1:1
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-07-08T09:16:09Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-07-08T09:16:05Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: ReplicaSet "kafka-broker0-5df4d8b876" has successfully progressed.
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-07-11T07:56:27Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-07-11T07:56:27Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
```

This is the deployment yaml for the zookeeper server

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zoo1
          image: digitalwonderland/zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
              value: zoo1
```

This is the deployment for the zookeeper server

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-deployment
  namespace: default
  uid: 08df5f66-8fa9-483d-9888-1bb0ac081a32
  resourceVersion: '178924'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2022-07-08T09:15:43Z'
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '1'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"zookeeper-deployment","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"replicas":2,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"zookeeper-1"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"zookeeper-1"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"ZOOKEEPER_ID","value":"1"},{"name":"ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1","value":"zoo1"}],"image":"digitalwonderland/zookeeper","name":"zoo1","ports":[{"containerPort":2181}]}]}}}}
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-07-08T09:15:43Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:spec:
          f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
          f:replicas: {}
          f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
          f:selector: {}
          f:strategy:
            f:rollingUpdate:
              .: {}
              f:maxSurge: {}
              f:maxUnavailable: {}
            f:type: {}
          f:template:
            f:metadata:
              f:labels:
                .: {}
                f:app: {}
            f:spec:
              f:containers:
                k:{"name":"zoo1"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:env:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"name":"ZOOKEEPER_ID"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                  f:image: {}
                  f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                  f:name: {}
                  f:ports:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"containerPort":2181,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:containerPort: {}
                      f:protocol: {}
                  f:resources: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
              f:dnsPolicy: {}
              f:restartPolicy: {}
              f:schedulerName: {}
              f:securityContext: {}
              f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-07-11T06:32:03Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
        f:status:
          f:availableReplicas: {}
          f:conditions:
            .: {}
            k:{"type":"Available"}:
              .: {}
              f:lastTransitionTime: {}
              f:lastUpdateTime: {}
              f:message: {}
              f:reason: {}
              f:status: {}
              f:type: {}
            k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
              .: {}
              f:lastTransitionTime: {}
              f:lastUpdateTime: {}
              f:message: {}
              f:reason: {}
              f:status: {}
              f:type: {}
          f:observedGeneration: {}
          f:readyReplicas: {}
          f:replicas: {}
          f:updatedReplicas: {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-1
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: zookeeper-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zoo1
          image: digitalwonderland/zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: '1'
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
              value: zoo1
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 2
  updatedReplicas: 2
  readyReplicas: 2
  availableReplicas: 2
  conditions:
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-07-08T09:15:50Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-07-08T09:15:43Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: >-
        ReplicaSet "zookeeper-deployment-54cf89ccc6" has successfully
        progressed.
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-07-11T06:32:03Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-07-11T06:32:03Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
```

This is the error I get in the consumer pod, that tries to subscribe to the kafka broker.

[image]

**How do I connect my consumer and producer pods to the Kafka Service?**

Answer (score 0):

The advertised name for the Kafka broker needs to be it's k8s service name. Similarly, it's advertised port needs to be the service port. If you change the advertised port away from the default, you'll need to modify the `containerPort` for it to be exposed.

Kafka clients cannot directly use a load balancer because they need to individually communicate with each broker. The load balancer service is only used for the initial bootstrap connection.

For your shown configs, clients within the cluster would connect to `kafka-service.svc.cluster.local:9092`, but they'd fail to connect until you modify the advertised settings since they'll fail to connect to `localhost:30718`.

Ultimately, I'd strongly suggest using an operator and/or Helm Chart for easiest configuration rather than worrying about incorrect settings.

Comment: Thank you for the input, unfortunately your suggestions did not work, my consumer still cannot connect to the kafka broker. I am not using Helm Chart at the moment because these were the instructions received.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include what changes you've made? And what error you get from the clients? All I can say is that you can simply look at existing Helm chart implementations and see how they setup the advertised listeners / ports and define Service resources then "untemplate" them

Comment: I have added a console log from the k8s dashboard of the consumer pod. Also, I have modified all of the attached deployment with the service and deployments from the k8s dashboard for zookeeper and kafka.

Comment: According to the error, it's still connecting to localhost, and not the service address. Make sure you gave the appropriate values to your Spring application